# Theming Paragraph at second item only

Tags: theming

I have already a theme using for my Paragraph, its view based so im doing this to print the fields:

```
<div class="col-md-5 p-4">
<div class="content">
<h3>{{content.field_title}}</h3>

<p>{{content.field_description}}</p>
<button class="main">{{content.field_link}}</button></div>
</div>
```

Everything is working as spected but i need to break on 2nd item and add a diferent class, how can i detect the 2nd item and change the class here? Im on a twig file.

Comment: Couldn't you wrap the whole thing in a div and use css: nth-child(2) {} ?

Or is it more than just a single class that needs to be different?

Comment: The class needs to be diferent at the second item.